# Compare tables from two different databases SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, testing, replication, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using SQL developer to connect to the databases, I am currently involved in Replication Testing:

Here are the links for the Source and Target:

```
**Source**
Host Name - n****-s**n.o*s.lab
Port - 1521
Service Name - stgdev

**Target**

Host Name - *pr****1.****b.lab
Port - 1522
Service Name - S******
```

Can anyone tell me how to write a query to compare tables from the above two databases, the databases are identical.
Say I want to compare Account table from both the above databases...what is the query. Please advise.

Comment: Can you create a database link in one of the two databases that points to the other database (or does such a database link already exist)?

Comment: No I haven’t created any database link, and neither I am sure if I am allowed to create a link. They have just given me a read only access. Please let me know the process of creating a link, if that is the option. I can ask the DBA here to give me access for creating a link. Also, where should the link be created on the source side or the target side….I would appreciate if you give the query…I am not  too good at SQL..

Answer (score 3):

if you have connectivity (db link) between two databases, you can use dbms_comparison package to setup scheduled comparison. in fact if you will frequently be doing this on multiple tables, you should probably look into it.

Or, you can always run a select * from table@source minus select @ from table@target and see differences but for large datasets it is not really efficient.

Look into dbms_comparison package [docs link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_comparison.htm#CHDHEFFJ)

Answer (score 1):

I work for Red Gate. We have a tool that performs data comparison of tables, allows you to view the differences and produce a deployment script that will make the data identical. Since you do not have a database link you can use between the databases I think our tool would work for you.

You get a full featured 14-day trial. You can download the tool here http://www.red-gate.com/products/oracle-development/.

Answer (score 1):

Squirrel-sql has a [pluging](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=plugins) for doing that !